# Spring Security 6 Config for non authenticated Endpoints not working

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

After updating Spring Boot to version 3.0.1 and Spring Security 6.0 the public endpoints without authentication are no longer working.
I'm followed the upgrade guide for Spring Security 6 and removed the *WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter*.

My Security Config:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true, jsr250Enabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Value("${auth0.audience}")
    private String audience;

    @Value("${spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.issuer-uri}")
    private String issuer;

    @Bean
    JwtDecoder jwtDecoder() {
        NimbusJwtDecoder jwtDecoder = (NimbusJwtDecoder)
                JwtDecoders.fromOidcIssuerLocation(issuer);

        OAuth2TokenValidator<Jwt> audienceValidator = new AudienceValidator(audience);
        OAuth2TokenValidator<Jwt> withIssuer = JwtValidators.createDefaultWithIssuer(issuer);
        OAuth2TokenValidator<Jwt> withAudience = new DelegatingOAuth2TokenValidator<>(withIssuer, audienceValidator);

        jwtDecoder.setJwtValidator(withAudience);

        return jwtDecoder;
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        return httpSecurity
                .csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())
                .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth
                        .requestMatchers("/rest/public/**").permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .sessionManagement(sess -> sess.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                .oauth2ResourceServer(OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer::jwt)
                .build();
    }
}
```

I'm using Postman to execute GET-Calls (eg. http://localhost:8090/rest/public/export/) to my application and it keeps telling me that authentication is need -> 401 Unauthenticated

Spring Security specific Startup Logs

```
swordEncoderAuthenticationManagerBuilder : No authenticationProviders and no parentAuthenticationManager defined. Returning null.
o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Will secure any request with [org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter@6acb45c1, org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@294c44b7, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter@5dd23809, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@13390a96, org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter@af9dd34, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@3f80d8c, org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.web.authentication.BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter@41bd6a0f, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@60ab895f, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@78bd02c8, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@30bbe83, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@57b33c29, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter@3c8fe8ad]
o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8090 (http) with context path
```

Logs when calling an public endpoint:

```
o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /rest/public/export/
o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
o.s.s.w.s.HttpSessionRequestCache        : Saved request http://localhost:8090/rest/public/export/?continue to session
```

I've followed this guide: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/migration/index.html

Comment: You can perfom the below mentioned checks:
1. Request you are making to the endpoint matches the pattern "/rest/public/**". If the request does not match this pattern, it will be denied access.
2. Make sure that the SecurityFilterChain bean is being correctly applied to your application. You can do this by adding some log statements to your SecurityConfig class and checking that the bean is being created and applied as expected.

Comment: 1.) It should be fine as the log when calling the public endpoint states the correct route (see the log in the initial post).
2.) I've added a logline but can't see it in the startup log nor in the runtime log.
Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: It seems to work after all.
So the fix was just to add **@Configuration**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to declare your class as `@Configuration` because otherwise the declared `@Bean`s won't be created and registered in the application context. It should look like this:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true, jsr250Enabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig {
```